# Sequence such that $x_{n+m} \geq x_n+x_m$, show that $(\frac{n}{x_n})$ converges (or not)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $x_n \geq  0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb N$ and that $$x_{n+m} \geq x_n+x_m \quad \forall n,m \in \mathbb N^* $$
I have the feeling that $(\frac{n}{x_n})$ converges but I have a little problem with the proof's end.
Can someone help me (the statement can also be wrong but I do not find counterexamples) ?

We have $x_{n+m} \geq x_n+x_m \quad \forall n,m \in \mathbb N^*$, we want to show that $(\frac{n}{x_n})$ converges :

Let's show that $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{x_n} = a$ where $a = inf\{\frac{n}{x_n} | n \in \mathbb N^*\}$ :

We have that $x_{pq+r} \geq x_{pq}+x_r \geq px_q+x_r$ with $p,q,r \in \mathbb N^*$ that gives $\frac{1}{x_{pq+r}} \leq \frac{1}{px_q+x_r}$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$, as $a$ is an inf, we have that $\exists q \in \mathbb N^*$ such that $ a \leq \frac{q}{x_q} \leq a + \frac{\epsilon}{2} $

Let $N>q$, so we have for $n > N$ and by Euclidean division on $n$, $$a \leq \frac{n}{x_n} \leq \frac{pq+r}{px_q+x_r} = \frac{pq}{px_q+x_r}+\frac{r}{px_q+x_r} \leq \frac{q}{x_q} + \frac{q}{px_q+x_r} \leq \frac{q}{x_q} + \frac{q}{px_q} = (1+\frac{1}{p})\frac{q}{x_q} \leq 2 \frac{q}{x_q} $$
Now I can write $a \leq \frac{n}{x_n}\leq 2a+\epsilon$ but we want $a \leq \frac{n}{x_n}\leq a+\epsilon$, is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: Also like to add that $x_n$ is increasing since $x_{n+1} \geq x_n + x_1 \implies x_{n+1} - x_n \geq x_1 \geq 0$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superadditivity for this version of Fekete's lemma.

Comment: Thank you, seems interesting !

Comment: Note that the $0$ sequence satisfies the conditions, but $\left(\frac n{x_n}\right)$ is undefined at every index. So there there is at least one exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $N > q$, pick $N >q\left(2+\dfrac{2a}\epsilon\right)$. If $n > N$, then
$$p > \dfrac nq - 1 > 1 + \dfrac {2a}\epsilon\\
p\dfrac \epsilon 2 > \dfrac \epsilon 2 + a\\\dfrac \epsilon 2 > \dfrac{a + \frac \epsilon 2}p$$

From your calculation,

$$\begin{align}a \le \dfrac n{x_n} &\le \left(1 + \dfrac1p \right)\dfrac q{x_q} \\&\le \left(1 + \dfrac1p\right)\left(a + \dfrac \epsilon 2\right)\\ 
&\le a + \dfrac \epsilon 2 + \dfrac{a + \frac \epsilon 2}p\\&\le a + \dfrac \epsilon 2 + \dfrac \epsilon 2\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you ! Quite technical but I checked steps 1 by 1 and seems all good !

Comment: The trick was recognizing that your replacing $1 +\frac 1p$ with $2$ was an unneccesary over estimation. For high $p$ (equivalently, high $n$) $1+\frac 1p$ is barely over $1$. The rest was just a little algebra to figure out what it would take to get the remainder $\frac 1p\left(a + \frac \epsilon 2\right)$ to be less than the needed $\frac\epsilon 2$.